# Weird error using Worklight and xsl transformation applied to a JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, xslt, xpath, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm encountering a weird problem and I'm not able to solve it.

I have a JSON reponse that looks like the following.

```
"values": [
    {
        "time": "2014-02-26T09:01:00+01:00",
        "data": [ "A", "B" ]
     },
     // other objects here..
 ]
```

Based on this, I apply the following xsl transformation.

```
<xsl:for-each select="values">
{
'time': <xsl:value-of select="time"></xsl:value-of>',
'val1': '<xsl:value-of select="data[1]"></xsl:value-of>',
'val2': '<xsl:value-of select="data[2]"></xsl:value-of>'
},
</xsl:for-each>
```

If time transform is present, Worklight gives me the following error.

```
"For input string: \"2014-02-26\"",
"The returned InvocationResult must be a valid JSON Object."
```

On the contrary, if I comment it out, all works perfectly.

What is the problem? Do I need to apply escape?

Comment: Can it be about `data[1], data[2]` instead `data[0], data[1]`? I'm asking because I don't know anything about xslt.

Comment: @user3280126 No. Since from my tests `data[0]` does not retrieve anything. Seems the index starts from 1.

Comment: If I comment `time` row, it works..

Comment: Also, possible mistyping `'` before `<xsl..` of `time`? I know they are very simple problems,but sometimes they are the most difficult ones to be seen.

Comment: @user3280126 Yes. The problem was the mistyping. Please convert your comment as an answer. I will mark it as resolved. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mistyped `'` before `<xsl..` of `time` in xsl transformation.